# cannot be indexed because it has no default property error

Tags: vb.net, winforms

Hello im newer in VB NET.
So, maybe my question will be seem naive.

VB code:

```
 Public Class InputBox
  Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)   Handles Button1.Click

Dim a, b, S, p
    a = InputBox("Enter length")
    b = InputBox("Enter width")
    S = a * b                           
    p = a + a + b + b               
  End Sub

End Class
```

in InputBox lines i get this error:

```
  Class 'LearningVB.InputBox' cannot be indexed because it has no default property
```

What this error means?

And any idea how can i solve the problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`InputBox` is a *class*, as declared here:

```
Public Class InputBox
```

If you're trying to use [the built-in VB helper function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6z0ak68w%28v=vs.90%29.aspx), I suspect you'll need to *either* change the name of your class (which sounds like it would be a good idea) *or* fully-qualify the function call. (I'm not even entirely sure how you'd do that, to be honest...)